# Resolving heteroskedasticity in linear regression models

Tags: r, regression, heteroscedasticity, weighted-regression

I am working on an age estimation method using 4 types of biological measurements as age predictors. I am using RStudio. 
So far, I have good results when I use linear regression (`lm(age~predictor)`), but I am encountering heteroskedasticity, and therefore cannot build prediction intervals for my models.
 
I have tried transformations to normalize the predictors using ln, inverse, and square root, but to no avail.
I have found a paper explaining the `wls` function, and I have used it in my models with the weight: $$\frac 1 {1+\frac{\text{predictor}^2} 2}$$ 
This has given me better age predictions, but does not solve the heteroskedasticity problem.

I have done some research, and apparently, one of my options is to create homoscedastic groups in my data by finding the data points where the residual variances change. 
For that, I have used the breakpoints function of strucchange, which gave me 5 breakpoints by default. 
I now want to give 6 different weights (weights are $\frac 1 {\text{var(age)}}$ of each interval) to my 6 intervals of data, but I cannot find a function to do that. I would greatly appreciate any help on the subject. 
Thanks.

Comment: I know this doesn't answer your question, but robust standard errors (Huber-White or otherwise, check out the `sandwich` package for those) won't do? Sure, the estimation will be less efficient but at least you'll be sure the variance-covariance matrix will be consistently estimated.

Comment: I think you would benefit from mixed effects models. A model where you can specify the variance structure would foresee heteroskedasticity. See Zuur et al. 2009 page 75+ for more details. Another good resource on MEM is Pinheiro and Bates.ž

Comment: I second @RomanLuštrik as to the use of mixed effects models. Within that framework you can explicitly model variance, and therefore heteroscedasticity. You can do it in R as well.

Comment: The function is `gls` from `nlme` package.

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help. I will try all of these suggestions and let you know how it goes.
Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you can use the `rlm()` function from the MASS package. I believe it's intended for datasets affected by outliers, but it's at least worth a try with your dataset.

[Here is a paper that describes the details of the function](http://www.dst.unive.it/rsr/BelVenTutorial.pdf).

**Description**:
Fit a linear model by robust regression using an M estimator.

**Details**:
Fitting is done by iterated re-weighted least squares (IWLS).

```
# Package examples
require(MASS)
summary(rlm(stack.loss ~ ., stackloss))
rlm(stack.loss ~ ., stackloss, psi = psi.hampel, init = "lts")
rlm(stack.loss ~ ., stackloss, psi = psi.bisquare)

# Using the diamonds data set
diam_rlm <- rlm(price ~ ., diamonds)
summary(diam_rlm)

# A plot as example
ggplot(diamonds, aes(carat,price)) +
  geom_point() +
  stat_smooth(method = "rlm") +
  xlim(0,2.9)
```

[image]

For the diamonds dataset, i'm sure you could improve the model with a transformation. However, as you aren't saying this works with your data i left the diamonds data "as is".